# C# Roslyn API, Reading a .cs file, updating a class, writing back to .cs file

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have this working code that will load a .cs file into the Roslyn SyntaxTree class, create a new PropertyDeclarationSyntax, insert it into the class, and re-write the .cs file. I'm doing this as a learning experience as well as some potential future ideas. I found that there doesn't really seem to be a full Roslyn API documentation anywhere and I'm unsure if I am doing this efficiently. My main concern is where I call 'root.ToFullString()' - whilst it works, is this the right way to do it?

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Roslyn.Compilers;
using Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp;

class RoslynWrite
{
    public RoslynWrite()
    {
        const string csFile = "MyClass.cs";

        // Parse .cs file using Roslyn SyntaxTree
        var syntaxTree = SyntaxTree.ParseFile(csFile);
        var root = syntaxTree.GetRoot();
        // Get the first class from the syntax tree
        var myClass = root.DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>().First();

        // Create a new property : 'public bool MyProperty { get; set; }'
        var myProperty = Syntax.PropertyDeclaration(Syntax.ParseTypeName("bool"), "MyProperty")
                            .WithModifiers(Syntax.Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword))
                            .WithAccessorList(
                            Syntax.AccessorList(Syntax.List(
                                Syntax.AccessorDeclaration(SyntaxKind.GetAccessorDeclaration)
                                    .WithSemicolonToken(Syntax.Token(SyntaxKind.SemicolonToken)),
                                Syntax.AccessorDeclaration(SyntaxKind.SetAccessorDeclaration)
                                    .WithSemicolonToken(Syntax.Token(SyntaxKind.SemicolonToken)))));

        // Add the new property to the class
        var updatedClass = myClass.AddMembers(myProperty);
        // Update the SyntaxTree and normalize whitespace 
        var updatedRoot = root.ReplaceNode(myClass, updatedClass).NormalizeWhitespace();

        // Is this the way to write the syntax tree? ToFullString?
        File.WriteAllText(csFile, updatedRoot.ToFullString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why exactly are you concerned about `ToFullString()`?

Comment: I can't find any documentation for the class and I'm not sure if this is the best way to extract the string representation of the syntax tree and re-output the CS file. I'm concerned there may be artefacts and other such things not suitable for code generation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answered on the Roslyn CTP forum [in this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f148d0e6-50c5-4666-ac45-adfcbee3a469/read-a-cs-file-add-property-to-class-write-back-to-cs-file):

> That approach is generally fine, though if you are worried about allocating a string for the text of the entire file, you should probably use IText.Write(TextWriter) instead of ToFullString().
>
> Keep in mind that it's possible to generate trees that will not round-trip through the parser.  For example, if you generated something that violates precedence rules, the SyntaxTree construction APIs won't catch that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; I figured there must be some more API specific forums!